# Нужны ли запятые: "Растения формирующие кочки" и т.п.?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли запятые в следующих предложениях.
 1. Растения "," формирующие кочки.
 2. Растения "," широко распространенные в горах.

Answer (score 1):

В обоих случаях это причастные обороты, стоящие после определяемого слова, поэтому запятая нужна. Если Вас устроил ответ, кликните о принятии его

Comment: Спасибо! Смутило то, что в опубликованных книгах встречается без запятых.

Comment: Книги из каких-нибудь очень частных типографий?))